# How to center a circle in an svg

Tags: html, svg

I'm lost as to how I can put a circle element at the center of an svg without it moving around or getting bigger and smaller as I resize the page.

I've tried viewBox but it doesn't do what I expected.

Comment: The `viewBox` would effectively center it within the SVG if you use it properly.

Comment: oh... silly me.. =) to get a coordinate system between (-1000 -1000) and (1000 1000)... the viewBox needs to be: viewBox="-1000 -1000 2000 2000" the last two values are lengths, not coordinates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<svg viewBox="-1 -1 2 2"> <!-- viewBox defines the coordinate system.-->
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="1" />
</svg>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

http://jsfiddle.net/QrNnN/

Comment: alternately: `viewbox` needs the stroke size added to the width and height, and the circle then needs to be offset by half the stroke size. if `stroke=6` then...
`viewbox= -3 -3 106 106`

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to the `viewBox` variant:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10"/>
</svg>
```

The circle would however get bigger if you zoom the whole page.

Another way is to use a zero-length path with rounded linecaps, like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M50 50" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="black" 
        fill="none" vector-effects="non-scaling-stroke"
        stroke-width="20"/>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dAEB9/

Answer (score 1):

Put your circle in group `<g>` and use `transform="translate(x, y)"`.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <g transform="translate(200, 200)">
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="200" style="" fill="darkOrange"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Result:
[image]

Simple example on JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mattez/0p2pstrf/

Comment: Can you use translate with percentages?